# Segmentation fault error with parameters

Tags: ios, swift

Getting a Segmentation fault 11 error. I have managed to narrow it down to the parameters in a method (trying to convert to Swift 3).

```
func uploadUserAvatar(photo: UIImage?, reachingRate: ((_ rate: Double) -> Void)?, completion: ((_ status: ResponseStatus, _ JSON: AnyObject?) -> Void)?) {

//Some code
}
```

and:

```
enum ResponseStatus {
    /**
     Successful request and the server gave a status of 'success'.
     */
    case success

    /**
     The request was unsuccessful or the server did not give a status of 'success'.
     */
    case failure

    /**
     Could not parse the JSON of the response.
     */
    case invalidJSON

    /**
     The user's is not authorized.
     */
    case unauthorized

    /**
     The request timed out.
     */
    case timedOut
}
```

Having trouble spotting the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: How is your ResponseStatus defined?

Comment: @fiks edited question

Comment: Thanks @KexAri. Do you have the ResponseStatus also defined somewhere else? Also where is your `uploadUserAvatar` defined?

Comment: `uploadUserAvatar` is defined in a view controller. `ResponseStatus` is only defined in the one file (The same file as the view controller class).

Comment: I have copy pasted your sample into another project and it works fine. I would try:
1. Renaming the ResponseStatus to some other name.
2. Check the logs to see if it really faults in this file.